# Suggestions for implementing a document management system in which some documents have runtime replaced fields

Tags: database, database-design, replace

One of my apps is a Document Management System in which the documents are stored as blob fields into a db. This is not a language specific question, anyway I put Delphi in tags since this is the community to which i tipically ask questions (and many people that uses Delphi faces these problems).

One feature I need to add is to programmatically add some data to the document. I make a simple example just to get the idea. One field is the date in which the document has been created. For this the user will type "a tag" for example `<DOCUMENT_DATE>` and the date will be automatically substituted when the docuemnt is extracted from db.

So I have 2 main concerns. ONe is what to use as "tag". The simplest thing is to use a text tag, so simply typing  into the docuemnt and then do Search & Replace text (using for example MS Word ActiveX). I already do this for other purposes. AN alternative could be using bookmarks or another technique.

The other question is strictly related with the previous.

How do I store it? My first idea is to store the document in DB with the "tags", so when it is "checked out" the user sees the tags, while when the user opens it (in readonly mode) he sees the subsituted text. (so in first case he sees  and in the second "12 october 2011").

In this way I store the file once, but every time it is opened there is an overhead in processing it and doing the Search Replace thing, that can be also relatively slow. So this is why I asked for other techniques. Like serach replace for bookmark. The fastest the better.

The alternative is to store the document twice: once with the "tags" and the other with the "substituted veresion". This will be good for performance: no Searh & Replace but simply when the document is openeed in "checkout" mode I will open the one with the tags, while whne I open it in readonly mode I will open the subsituted one.

This of course takes more storage, for every document version (revision1, revision2, ...) I need to store 2 files.

I feel double storage is the best, because it won't affect perfomance at all, I mean it will be as fast as now, just the checkin process will be slower since I need to save 2 files and not one. Moreover by not enabling this auto substitution feature on all documents by default I won't have double db size.

But anyway I would like to hear some comments, since it is a quite crucial decision.

Answer (score 2):

It really does not make sense to store identical data twice.
in fact it is a really bad idea, mainly from a consistancy point of view.
The way you do this is to store stuff in different tables and create links between the tables.

This is a process called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Here's an example loosely inspired by your post using MySQL:

```
TABLE document
--------------
id UNSIGNED INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
data BLOB

TABLE tag
------------
id UNSIGNED INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
tag VARCHAR(20)

TABLE tag_link
-------------------
tag_id UNSIGNED INTEGER,
reference_nr UNSIGNED INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, reference_nr)
FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (reference_nr) REFERENCES post(reference_nr) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

TABLE post
----------------
reference_nr UNSIGNED INTEGER NOT NULL,
revision UNSIGNED INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
document_id UNSIGNED INTEGER,
title VARCHAR(255),
creation_date TIMESTAMP,
other_fields .....
PRIMARY KEY (reference_nr, revision),
FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES document(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON CASCADE UPDATE
```

Now you can add tags to a post, all revisions of a post share the same tags.
Revisions of a post can link to the same document, or to different documents no need to duplicate data.

If you want to get all the lastest revisions of documents with certain tags, you use the following query:

```
SELECT p.title, d.data, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS tags
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN d.data ON (p.document_id = d.id)
INNER JOIN taglink tl ON (tl.reference_nr = p.reference_nr)
INNER JOIN tags t ON (tl.tag_id = t.id)
WHERE t.tag IN ('test','test2')
GROUP BY p.reference_nr  /*only works in MySQL because other db's do not support ANSI SQL 2003*/
HAVING p.revision = MAX(p.revision)
ORDER BY p.creation_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two other possibilities worth considering.

**1. Use RTF**

If your document templates are Word documents, I'd rather store them as RTF.

RTF is just plain ASCII, and even if it is a proprietary format, it is well documented, and can be easily parsed. Word is able to save its content and read it as RTF. If you have pictures within, it can grow, but you can zip it before storing as BLOB in your database (and you may embed EMF pictures).

Then you can process those RTF content very fast in your code, changing all `<DOCUMENT_DATE>` using the latest version of the date field value.

I use this technique in several applications, and it gives very good results. See for instance how our [SynProject tool](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SynProject) generates Word documents from plain text, replacing tags, setting bookmarks or indexes on the fly. With RTF, you can do much more than just replacing a tag, but create a whole document easily.

For end-user input, you can use a basic `TRichEdit` or a more advanced (but not free) `TRichView` instead of Word.

You may consider using HTML instead of RTF, but it is much less printing-friendly.

**2. Use a report engine**

Another possibility could be to use a code-based report engine, then create PDF files.

Our Open Source units can be used from a [simple reporting class](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=41) to create easily the file content, preview it on screen and/or print/export as PDF. It is much easier than RTF to work with, but the layout has to be set in your code, or with text-based / wiki-like templates to be stored in your DB.

Comment: RTF is heavy. RTF docs with a few images on it are many MB when a word doc is 100kB. The example is extreme when there is a logo on the header: RTF will use one image per page,  (bmp by the way), Word is smarter. What I need to do is to slightly modifin a current feature so I cannot change it with a report engine. Ia lready use Report Buiklder to create some reports, but in this case these are not reports, but normal docs in which i just replace 2 fields. Thanks anyway.

Comment: About RTF, you can include the picture as a BLOB column value, and replace it with a tag (you can insert pictures either in hexa, either in binary within the RTF - so you can save half the size). Once imported in Word, you won't notice the difference. And I proposed to compress the RTF before inserting into the DB - this will reuse the picture even if the same is one per page. And there is a dedicated HEADER RTF tag to add it only once. About reporting, take a look at our classes: you can easily use it to implement a wiki-like plain text template.